# Unable to filter on AWS RDS stack-name

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, tags, command-line-interface, rds

Why doesn't this just work? Pulling the tags listed with my rds instance:

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name arn:aws:rds:eu-central-1:12345678901:db:pa1jyg4oc56mipf

{
    "TagList": [
        {
            "Value": "DatabaseRdsInstance",
            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id"
        },
        {
            "Value": "production-test-123",
            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
        },
        {
            "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:12345678901:stack/production-test-123/1234abc-56f9-11e5-b10e-50d501fbb66e",
            "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id"
        }
    ]
}
```

Filtering on one of those tags fails:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --filters Name="tag:aws:cloudformation:stack-name",Values=production-test-123
A client error (InvalidParameterValue) occurred when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: Unrecognized filter name: tag:aws:cloudformation:stack-name
```

Nor does it work when I leave the `tag` part from the Name:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --filters Name="aws:cloudformation:stack-name",Values="production-test-123"

A client error (InvalidParameterValue) occurred when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: Unrecognized filter name: aws:cloudformation:stack-name
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html) the `--filters` option is currently unsupported unfortunately.

You will have to perform the filtering on the tags on the client side instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `list-tag-resources` you can try with `resourcegroupstaggingapi`.

`aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters rds:db --tag-filters Key=aws:cloudformation:stack-id,Values=arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:12345678901:stack/production-test-123/1234abc-56f9-11e5-b10e-50d501fbb66e`. It should work